# The emergence of space-time from entangled states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, holographic-principle

I recently read an article by Yasunori Nomura (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05263), in which he says that space-time is an emerging phenomenon. At the same time, space-time disappears when the holographic degrees of freedom are maximally entangled and when there is no entanglement at all.

Do I understand correctly that one can say:

1. Before the appearance of space-time, the universe was in a state in which the entanglement between the holographic degrees of freedom was zero.
2. Can there be a situation in quantum mechanics in which the subsystems are absolutely not entangled and suddenly, spontaneously, begin to entangle?

Comment: If the Hamiltonian acting on the total system contains an interaction term, they will entangle on their own. E.g. the two electrons in a Helium atom are entangled in all of position, momentum, and spin.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer That is, they will be absolutely not entangled for some time, then suddenly they will get entangled?

Comment: I am not sure to understand, but to use that machinery the cosmological constant should be negative (AdS). Our universe has a positive constant. How should one  fix this problem?

Comment: @ValterMoretti I don’t know why you say that ‘to use that machinery the cosmological constant must be negative’, can you please explain the premises of this claim.

Comment: @Wakabaloola By reading (quite superficially) the paper you quoted, I have had the impression that the thesis promoted in the work relies upon the assumption that the cosmological scenario is essentially an AdS spacetime (at least at space infinity, am I right?). Well, it is very very well known that our universe has a **positive** cosmological constant whereas AdS has a **negative** cosmological constant. How does **our** spacetime can be viewed as an emergent property of entangled states, if our spacetime is not the one assumed in the paper?

Comment: @ValterMoretti i believe the idea that spacetime may emerge from entanglement has nothing to do with AdS or negative curvature spacetime. and i say the idea, because (modulo some oversimplified toy models) that’s all it is at this stage. but i do believe it is interesting to explore in detail.  (i didn’t quote any paper btw)

Comment: The point is that the spacetime needs a boundary to implement some holographic procedure. This is given for free in AdS. However, indeed, the abstract referes to AdS but also to the *holographic boundary of a FRW spacetime in the limit of dS spacetime*. I am curious to understand what that boundary is...Thank you for your feedback